# Getting PHP Errors to show up in a Modal

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get it where if there is an error when the user registers it will pop up with a modal like this. (I have it right now with a button to test it out) 
[image]

So my question is how do I get it to pop up with out a button? Like if someone happened to forget their username, the modal would pop up with the error, But How do I get it where If there is an error the modal will pop up with it.?

```
            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-df float-button-dark waves-effect waves-effect waves-button waves-float waves-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Primary</button>


                            <div class="modal modal-default fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Whoops! Something Happened.</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">


                                <?php
            //check for any errors
            if(isset($error)){
                foreach($error as $error){
                    echo '<p> - '.$error.'</p>';
                }
            }

            //if action is joined show sucess
            if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){


                echo "<h2 class='alert alert-success'>Registration successful, please check your email to activate your account.</h2>";

            }
            ?>   


                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want show the modal when user submitted form, or while enter fields ?

Comment: Just the Modal, So if theirs an error like above, there was no password or username or email entered it would pop up the modal and show the user the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be useful:

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#idForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs = {
        user : {
          field : $('#fieldUser'),
          error : 'field user required !'
        },
        password : {
          field : $('#fieldPassword'),
          error : 'field password required !'
        },
        email : {
          field : $('#fieldEmail'),
          error : 'field email required !'
        }      
    };
    var errors = new Array();

    for(input in inputs) {
    //console.log(inputs[input].field.empty())
      if(inputs[input].field.val() === "") {
      //alert(inputs[input].error)
        errors.push(inputs[input].error);
      }
    }
    // errors var contain all errors
    if(errors.length > 0) {
      // here show your modal with errors.
      //$('#idModal').show();
      //alert(errors);
      var errorsJoin = errors.join('\n');
      alert('please review this errors : \n' + errorsJoin);
    } else {
      alert('sign up successfully');

    }

  })
  })

  </script>  

  <form method="POST" id="idForm">
    user : <input type="text" id="fieldUser"> <br>   
    pass :<input type="text" id="fieldPassword">  <br>
    email :<input type="text" id="fieldEmail">  <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">  
  </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
```